# Inject I18n text into javascript using tapestry-3

Tags: internationalization, tapestry

I'm adding Internationalization to a tapestry app.

Is there a standard tapestry-3 technique to Internationalize strings that appear as Javascript literals?

For example:

```
<input jwcid="submitBtn" type="submit" accesskey="U" value="Update" class="actionBtn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure that you want to do that?');"/></td>
```

Can I simply replace the question with a tapestry  tag in this and any other context?  Say something like:

```
<input jwcid="submitBtn" type="submit" accesskey="U" value="Update" class="actionBtn" onclick="return confirm('<span key="AreYouSure">Are you sure that you want to do that?</span>');"/></td>
```

This means that the source file contains an element inside an attribute which would be fine inside a JSP.  Does tapestry-3 handle this? If not, is there a way to do this in tapestry-3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine in T3 as well - another option is to initialize your i18n js strings at the top of the page:

```
<script>
  var jsStrings = { 
    sure : '<span key="AreYouSure"/>',
    ...
  };
</script>
```

and then just use them:

```
<input jwcid="submitBtn" onclick="return confirm(jsStrings.sure);"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the best way to go.